# В каком формате в бд хранить номер лицевого счёта?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Номер лицевого счёта содержит 20 цифр. Какой тип указать для столбца в mysql, где будут храниться номера лицевого счёта? Использую миграцию в laravel.

> $table->integer('personal_account')

или

> $table->bigInteger('personal_account')

или лучше в строке хранить?

Comment: 20 цифр ни в BIGINT, ни тем более в INT не поместится. Или CHAR(20), или DECIMAL(20,0)

Comment: в BIGINT UNSIGNED поместится, но первые цифры до 184

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строке потому, что:

- нет арифметических операций
- от платежных систем он приходит строкой, штрихкоды тоже из строки формируются
- строка не округлится `1.811235+e10`
- контрольные числа и хэши считаются на строке
- decimal всеравно хранит в строке
- сортировка не важна

В целых числах разбив на префикс и номер договора:

- Если индекс таблицы не помещается в память